# How to set from date and todate in date time picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to set date in date time picker from date and to date, like

from date : 27/7/2015
To date: 5/8/2015

I am having these two values I have to set values in date time picker. If I click datetimepicker I should show only these date's available to pick date, other dates should not pick.

Date format default is coming like MM/dd/yyyy i want like dd/MM/YYYY

my html control

```
 $("#dtStartDate").datetimepicker();
```

advance thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`minDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) and [`maxDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) options.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(2015, 7, 27),
    maxDate: new Date(2015, 8, 5)
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>Date:
  <input type="text" id="datepicker">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps  :

```
  minDate: new Date(2014, 8, 14),//Min date shown on Datepicker
  maxDate: new Date(2015, 8, 14)//max date shown on datepicker
```

or else :

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker(
{
locale: {
  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
},
startDate: '2013-01-01',
endDate: '2013-12-31'
}, 
function(start, end, label) {
alert("A new date range was chosen: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
});
```

then Then attach the picker to the element you want to trigger it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery  /1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
```